# How can I find the bytes of a wav file ?

Tags: c, wav, fseek

I was 100% sure that the bytes of a wav file are `chunkSize + 8`,What I've been trying to do 
is:

`fseek(file_pointer, chunkSize+8-4, SEEK_SET)`

and then use

`fread(rev, 4, 1, file_pointer)`

to put the last 4 bytes to the array rev `unsigned char rev[4]`. But the bytes it puts in rev are for sure not the 4 last bytes. I've been working on the project for so many hours and I still can't find why this isn't working. If someone can tell me the correct answer I will build a statue of him right now.

Comment: If you want the last 4 bytes of a file, why aren't you using `SEEK_END`?

Comment: The actual problem is the reversion of a wav file. so when i read the 4 last then i with fseek i will point to the next 4(direction to the begining) i will read them ...then the next 4. I have to know when to stop. thats why

Comment: How big can this file possibly be?  Why not just read it all into memory, reverse it, and then write it back out?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the last 4 bytes of a file, you can use `SEEK_END`, like so:

```
fseek(file_pointer, -4, SEEK_END);
```

The `fread` should then return the last four bytes.

Comment: because i won't know when to stop. Because after taking this 4 bytes i want the next 4 bytes and the next...till i reach the header((44 bytes from the begening is the end of header) where i will stop

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand - are you trying to read the last 4 bytes of a wav file? Is the wav file embedded in another file?

Comment: The actual question is why the fseek(file_pointer, chunkSize+8-4, SEEK_SET) isn't working. my goal is to reverse the wav file. if i solve why this isn't working i will solve the whole problem.

Comment: Try outputting the value of `chunkSize` and see if it's what you expect.